# Log4j: How to generate log file daily with headers using DailyRollingFileappender even if there are no logs triggered

Tags: java, log4j

How to generate log file daily with headers using DailyRollingFileappender even if there are no logs triggered from application.

So once the file is rolled, previous days file should have only headers

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j `DailyRollingFileAppender` will not output an empty file if no logging has occurred. From the implementation:

```
/**
* This method differentiates DailyRollingFileAppender from its
* super class.
*
* <p>Before actually logging, this method will check whether it is
* time to do a rollover. If it is, it will schedule the next
* rollover time and then rollover.
* */
protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
```

If you can upgrade to log4j2 you can use the [TimeBased Triggering Policy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/appenders.html#TimeBased_Triggering_Policy)

> The TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy causes a rollover once the date/time
>   pattern no longer applies to the active file. This policy accepts an
>   interval attribute which indicates how frequently the rollover should
>   occur based on the time pattern and a modulate boolean attribute.

And your configuration should be like this - you can read further explanation in [here](https://www.boraji.com/log4j-2-rollingfileappender-example) :

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile">
  <FileName>C:/log/mylog.log</FileName>
  <FilePattern>C:/log/time-based-logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.log.zip</FilePattern>
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.zip [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
  </Policies>
  <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
</RollingFile>
```